# How to cut a markdown link on the same line e.g. from `[` to `)`?

Tags: cut-copy-paste, filetype-markdown

If I'm anywhere on a line that contains e.g.:

```
[text1](link to text1)
```

How do I cut from `[` to `)` ?

Comment: If by cut you mean delete, then something like `:%s:\v\[.{-}\)::g` should work. But if you mean cut and put it in clipboard, then that'd require different approach.

Comment: Note that Markdown links' parentheses are balanced (in CommonMark, at least), so this cannot be done with a regular expression. See `[Disambiguation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disambiguation_(disambiguation))` → [Disambiguation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disambiguation_(disambiguation)).

Answer (score 5):

I'd just do this in normal mode: <kbd>0</kbd><kbd>f</kbd><kbd>[</kbd><kbd>d</kbd><kbd>f</kbd><kbd>)</kbd>.

If this is something you're doing a lot, then you could create a mapping:

```
:nnoremap <leader>d 0f[df)
```

But once you're going that far, you probably want something a bit more sophisticated, such as a [custom text object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73912649/328936), or, ideally, a pair of them so you can handle whitespace appropriately (like how `iw` and `aw` work for words).

Comment: Notice that `0f[` fails the criteria "If I'm anywhere on a line" if the markdown link starts at the very beginning of the line and the line contains the `[` elsewhere.

Comment: @hlovdal Good point! But in practice, if my cursor were already on the `[` I wouldn’t press `0`. In fact, in practice, I’d never press `0`! I’d just use `f`/`F` accordingly.

Comment: @hlovdal I guess `$F[` solves the start of line problem, but not the “another [ in the way” problem. :(

Answer (score 1):

This command copy the first Markdown link of the current line:

```
exe 's/\[.*)/&/' | norm gny
```

This command copy the next Markdown link:

```
exe "norm /\[.*)\<CR>gny"
```

The first bit (`exe 's/[.*)/&/`) search for the link on the current line and replace by itself.

The second part (`norm gny`) select the match and yank it.

If you prefer to cut you could do:

```
exe 's/\[.*)/&/' | norm gnd
```

This command cut the next Markdown link:

```
exe "norm /\[.*)\<CR>gnd"
```

Comment: For cut, `gnd` would suffice.

Comment: Indeed. Thanks for the hint :-). I believe the solution of @Rich is better ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your position is at the starting `[`<sup>1</sup>, I would use <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>%</kbd><kbd>.</kbd> (or <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>%</kbd><kbd>d</kbd><kbd>%</kbd>).

---

<sup>1</sup>Actually you can have the cursor a bit in front as well if there is any connected preceding text you want, e.g.

```
The [question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/38796/843), the [answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/38807/843).
```

after <kbd>0</kbd><kbd>f</kbd><kbd>,</kbd> then <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>%</kbd><kbd>.</kbd> gives

```
The [question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/38796/843).
```